Window keybindings ( e.g. <space>wh and <space>wl ) not working after session restore in LazyVim
The keybindings space>wh and wl etc. work when I create new files. However, when I close LazyVim and reopen it with a session restore, it stops working. There is no reaction. I cannot switch to another window except via the mouse, and only one window is open, although I can see all the tabs. There used to be splits, which have also disappeared. It happens both with the built-in session manager of LazyVim as well as auto-session. Can anyone please help?
I tried several different session managers once I discovered it happens only after a session restore. But it happens with all of them. Everything after w is ignored.
